# Having trouble vertically centering a dynamic image

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I need to vertically center an image, I don't know it's dimensions ahead of time so the only option I really have is using `tables` or `css tables` I believe.

I thought I'd give css tables a go but I still can't get an image to vertically center in them.

My HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table_row">
            <div class="table_cell">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3560817062/a9bda79c4d2bfc3353a4fbc0a14e6080.jpeg" alt="Main Image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.table_row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
    width: 411px;
    min-width: 411px;
    max-width: 411px;
    height: 341px;
    min-height: 341px;
    max-height: 341px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.image img {

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DLuU/

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all you don't need the `<div>` for table-row you can work only with the `table-cell`, to solve the align issue assign the `height:100%` for the table and table-cell:

```
.table {
    height:100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.table_cell {
    height:100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DLuU/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use line-height and vertical-center like:

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3560817062/a9bda79c4d2bfc3353a4fbc0a14e6080.jpeg" alt="Main Image"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image
{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    line-height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}

.image img
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your table does not have enough height to cover the outer div. You can give a specific height to it.

```
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height:350px;

}
```